# nested Python numpy arrays dimension confusion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array `c` constructed as follows:

```
a = np.zeros((2,4))
b = np.zeros((2,8))
c = np.array([a,b])
```

I would have expected `c.shape` to be `(2,1)` or `(2,)` but instead it is `(2,2)`. Additionally, what I want to do is concatenate a column vector of ones onto `a`, but by accessing it through `c` in the following way:

```
c0 = c[0] # I would have expected this to be 'a'
np.concatenate((np.ones((c0.shape[0], 1)), c0), axis=1)
```

This of course doesn't work because `c[0]` does not equal `a` as I expected, and I get

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

I need some way to have an array (or list) of pairs, each pair component being a numpy array, and I need to access the first array in the pair in order to concatenate a column vector of ones to it. My application is machine learning and my data will be coming to me in the format described, but I need to modify the data at the start in order to add a bias element to it.

**EDIT:** I'm using Python 2.7 and Numpy 1.8.2

Comment: Your example code does not work for me, I get a `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,4) into shape (2)`  when assigning `c`.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7, is that maybe the difference?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7, too. I believe I found an answer nevertheless, at least if I understood your question right...

Comment: That seems strange, I still get the error I posted

Comment: And I have numpy version 1.8.2, maybe that?

Comment: Why not just use `c = [a,b]`? It is possible to make `c` an array of object dtype, in which you could store NumPy arrays of arbitrary shape -- `c = np.empty((2,), dtype='object')`; `c[:] = [a,b]`-- , but object arrays do not enjoy any speed benefit over a plain Python list. You might use it for NumPy slicing syntax, but I have yet to see a compelling use case.

Comment: By the way, with NumPy v.1.9.0, `np.array([a,b])` raises the same `ValueError` that Dux mentioned.

Comment: If you have two numpy arrays in your pair, that do not have the same shape, you cannot combine them to one array. They don't fit. Except if you use HappyLeapSecond's solution

Comment: I don't want to combine the arrays a,b though, I just want to store them together in the same structure. I don't care if it's an array or list or tuple or whatever, a and b just somehow have to be paired together, and then whatever that pair is, the pairs need to be collected together into some structure (array or list or something). I just did it in a way that I thought would work, and it didn't. That is why I need someone's help to give me a way that works.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `c = [a, b]` fits the bill.

Comment: @HappyLeapSecond BINGO. That is what I needed, I clearly don't understand the subtleties of Python arrays, I'm coming from Matlab. Thanks! Write that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: `numpy` arrays are close to the Matlab matrices - the elements are all the same kind of number (or character).  Python lists are closer to the Matlab cell arrays, in that they can contain mixed types of items, and can be nested.  And Matlab structures are more like Python dictionaries or objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, nested NumPy arrays of NumPy arrays are not very useful. 
If you are using NumPy for speed, usually it is best to stick with NumPy arrays
with a homogenous, basic numeric dtype.

To place two items in a data structure such that `c[0]` returns the first item,
and `c[1]` the second, a list (or tuple) such as `c = [a, b]` will do.

---

By the way, if you are using the  `statemodels` package, then you can add a constant column with `sm.add_constant`:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

a = np.random.randint(10, size=(2,4))
print(a)
# [[2 3 9 6]
#  [0 2 1 1]]
print(sm.add_constant(a))
[[ 1.  2.  3.  9.  6.]
 [ 1.  0.  2.  1.  1.]]
```

Note however that if `a` already contains a constant column, no extra column is added:

```
In [126]: sm.add_constant(np.zeros((2,4)))
Out[126]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: "nested NumPy arrays of NumPy arrays are not very useful." This comment isn't very useful. Some libraries use nested NumPy arrays of NumPy arrays and there is no avoiding them.

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you want to use is `hstack`:

```
a = np.zeros((2,4))  # 4 column vectors of length 2
b = np.ones((2,1))   # 1 column vector of length 2

c = np.hstack((a, b))
print c
# [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

Regarding the problem concatenating your `a` and `b`: This cannot be done in a obvious way. Concatenation means stacking on top of each other in an additional dimension. Your data does not fit on one another though...

Comment: This ignores the fact that I will have essentially an array of pairs of arrays though, which is my problem. This looks like another way to do np.concatenate but I still need to go through the steps of accessing the array in my way described.

Comment: Ok, seems I did not understand your question after all. What is your desired output? A two-dimensional array, or a three-dimensional one?

Comment: @aconkey: you say, "I need some way to have an array (or list) of pairs", which is what this gives (by my interpretation, anyway).  Could you describe specifically what it is about this "array of pairs" that does not match what you mean by an "array of pairs"?

Comment: @tom10: OP wants `c[0]` to return `a`.