# Split file to chunk

Tags: python-3.x, file, numpy, split

I am trying to split a file formatted as:

```
@some 
@garbage
@lines
@target G0.S0
@type xy
 -0.108847E+02  0.489034E-04
 -0.108711E+02  0.491023E-04
 -0.108574E+02  0.493062E-04
 -0.108438E+02  0.495075E-04
 -0.108302E+02  0.497094E-04
 ....Unknown line numbers...
&
@target G0.S1
@type xy
 -0.108847E+02  0.315559E-04
 -0.108711E+02  0.316844E-04
 -0.108574E+02  0.318134E-04
 ....Unknown line numbers...
&
@target G1.S0
@type xy
 -0.108847E+02  0.350450E-04
 -0.108711E+02  0.351669E-04
 -0.108574E+02  0.352908E-04
&
@target G1.S1
@type xy
 -0.108847E+02  0.216396E-04
 -0.108711E+02  0.217122E-04
 -0.108574E+02  0.217843E-04
 -0.108438E+02  0.218622E-04
```

The `@target Gx.Sy` combination is unique and each set of data is always termineted by `&`.

I have managed to split the file in chunk as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

try:
  filename = sys.argv[1]
  print(filename)
except IndexError:
  print("ERROR: Required filename not provided")

with open(filename, "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    if line.startswith("@target"):
      print(line.split()[-1].split("."))

x=[];y=[]
with open(filename, "r") as f:
  for key,group in it.groupby(f,lambda line: line.startswith('@target')):
    print(key)
    if not key:
        group = list(group)
        group.pop(0)
        # group.pop(-1)
        print(group)
        for i in range(len(group)):
          x.append(group[i].split()[0])
          y.append(group[i].split()[1])
        nx=np.array(x)
        ny=np.array(y)
```

I have two problem:

1) The preamble lines before the real data is also grouped, so the script does not work if there is any preamble. It is impossible to predict how many lines that would be; But I am trying to group **after** the `@target` and

2) I want to name the arrays as  G0[S0,S0] and G1[S1,S2]; but I cant do this.

Kindly Help

**UPDATE**:
I am trying to store those data in a nested np array of G0[S0,S1,...], G1[S0,S1,..] so that I can use it in matplotlib.

Comment: Could you give as an example what the output would be in this case?

Comment: @Loquacious Hi, I have made an update; does this makes sense?

Comment: If you want to name the arrays, then you'll need a dict. Could it be that you actually want a "list of lists of lists of coordinates"? i.e. list of G, each G is a list of S, each S is a list of point pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions below get the job done:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

def read_without_preamble(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith('@target'):
            return lines[i:]

def split_into_chunks(lines):
    chunks = defaultdict(dict)
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('@target'):
            GS_str = line.strip().split()[-1].split('.')
            G, S = map(lambda x: int(x[1:]), GS_str)
            chunks[G][S] = []
        elif line.startswith('@type xy'):
            pass
        elif line.startswith('&'):
            chunks[G][S] = np.asarray(chunks[G][S])
        else:
            xy_str = line.strip().split()
            chunks[G][S].append(map(float, xy_str))
    return chunks
```

To split your file into chunks you just need to run this code:

```
try:
  filename = sys.argv[1]
  print(filename)
except IndexError:
  print("ERROR: Required filename not provided")

data = read_without_preamble(filename)
chunks = split_into_chunks(data)
```

#### Stepwise demo

`chunks` is a dictionary in which the key is `G` (either `0` or `1`):

```
In [415]: type(chunks)
Out[415]: dict

In [416]: for k in chunks.keys(): print(k)
0
1
```

The value of dictionary `chunks` is another dictionary in which the key is `S` (`0`, `1`, or `2` in this example) and the value is a NumPy array containing the numeric data for `Gi.Sn`. You can access this chunk of data like this: `chunks[i][n]`, where indices `i` and `n` are the values of `G` and `S`, respectively.

```
In [417]: type(chunks[0])
Out[417]: dict

In [418]: for k in chunks[0].keys(): print(k)
0
1
2

In [419]: type(chunks[1][2])
Out[419]: numpy.ndarray

In [420]: chunks[1][2]
Out[420]: 
array([[ -1.08851000e+01,   2.53058000e-05],
       [ -1.08715000e+01,   2.55353000e-05],
       [ -1.08579000e+01,   2.57745000e-05],
       [ -1.08443000e+01,   2.60225000e-05],
       [ -1.08306000e+01,   2.62617000e-05],
       [ -1.08170000e+01,   2.65097000e-05],
       [ -1.08034000e+01,   2.67666000e-05]])
```

`chunks[i][n].shape[0]` is `2` for any `i` and `n`, but `chunks[i][n].shape[1]` can take any value, i.e. the number of rows of numeric data may vary from one chunk to another.

#### formatted_file.txt

This is the file I used in the sample run. It consists of six chunks, namely `G0.S0`, `G0.S1`, `G0.S2`, `G1.S0`, `G1.S1`, and `G1.S2`.

```
@some 
@garbage
@lines
@target G0.S0
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.127435E-03
 -0.108715E+02  0.127829E-03
 -0.108579E+02  0.128191E-03
 -0.108443E+02  0.128502E-03
 -0.108306E+02  0.128726E-03
 -0.108170E+02  0.128838E-03
 -0.108034E+02  0.128751E-03
&
@target G0.S1
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.472694E-04
 -0.108715E+02  0.474233E-04
 -0.108579E+02  0.475837E-04
 -0.108443E+02  0.477448E-04
 -0.108306E+02  0.479052E-04
 -0.108170E+02  0.480669E-04
 -0.108034E+02  0.482279E-04
&
@target G0.S2
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.253654E-04
 -0.108715E+02  0.255956E-04
 -0.108579E+02  0.258346E-04
 -0.108443E+02  0.260825E-04
 -0.108306E+02  0.263303E-04
 -0.108170E+02  0.265781E-04
 -0.108034E+02  0.268349E-04
&
@target G1.S0
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.108786E-03
 -0.108715E+02  0.109216E-03
 -0.108579E+02  0.109651E-03
 -0.108443E+02  0.110116E-03
 -0.108306E+02  0.110552E-03
 -0.108170E+02  0.111011E-03
 -0.108034E+02  0.111489E-03
&
@target G1.S1
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.278045E-04
 -0.108715E+02  0.278711E-04
 -0.108579E+02  0.279384E-04
 -0.108443E+02  0.280050E-04
 -0.108306E+02  0.280723E-04
 -0.108170E+02  0.281395E-04
 -0.108034E+02  0.282074E-04
&
@target G1.S2
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.253058E-04
 -0.108715E+02  0.255353E-04
 -0.108579E+02  0.257745E-04
 -0.108443E+02  0.260225E-04
 -0.108306E+02  0.262617E-04
 -0.108170E+02  0.265097E-04
 -0.108034E+02  0.267666E-04
&
```

Comment: This is an inadequate solution for a couple reasons: 1. you're reading the entire file into memory using `readlines()`, which could be disastrous, and 2. you're assuming the file will only have two G chunks. I hope OP will consider my solution as an alternative.

Comment: @waterboy5281, there's an issue in your list-based approach. If the data file is arranged differently (for example if the first chunk is `G3.S0`), `G[0,0]` would return `G3.S0` rather than `G0.0`. Besides, your code throws an error due to the fact that you used `x` as an index variable in the list comprehensions.

Comment: You are the most wise. Thank you for pointing out these errors.

Comment: I've addressed your comments with a new version of my answer.

Comment: Edited my answer to deal with any number of G chunks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using a generator and `np.genfromtxt`. Advantage: Light on memory. It filters the file *on the fly* hence does *not* require loading the entire thing into memory for processing.

**UPDATE:**

I streamlined the code and changed the output format to array of arrays.
If for example `G` ranges between `0...3` and `S` ranges between `0...5` then it creates a 4x6 array containing arrays.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import dropwhile, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def load_chunks(f):
    f = open(f, 'rt') if isinstance(f, str) else f
    f = filter(lambda l: not l.strip() in ("", "&"), f)
    tok = "@target", "@type"
    fg = dropwhile(itemgetter(0), groupby(f, lambda l: not l.split()[0] in tok))
    I, D = [], []
    for k, g in fg:
        info = next(l.split() for l in g)[1]
        I.append([int(key[1:]) for key in info.split('.')])
        D.append(np.genfromtxt((l.encode() for l in next(fg)[1])))
    G, S = np.array(I).T
    res = np.empty((np.max(G)+1, np.max(S)+1), dtype=object)
    res[G, S] = D
    return res

fn = <your_file_name>

ara = load_chunks(fn)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your solution. But I am not sure how to put my file to it. may be `f=open(f)`?

Comment: you can either specify a file name or an open file and put it in the place of `fn`

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT* - I took the feedback on my list approach and decided to switch it to a dict. This solution has the advantage of being light on memory consumption and fully dynamic (i.e. does not depend on knowing the number of G chunks *a priori*.

---

I've made use of the `re` package, which is similar to how `numpy` handles I/O via `loadtxt()`. Also, since there's really [no point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493109/nested-python-numpy-arrays-dimension-confusion) creating a nested numpy array of numpy arrays, I am just returning a nested built-in `list` of numpy arrays. Since your data is inhomogenous, this approach is just as efficient (and much simpler):

```
import numpy as np
import re
from collections import defaultdict

COMMENT_REGEX = re.compile(str('@'))
TERMINATION_REGEX = re.compile(str('&'))
TARGET_REGEX = re.compile(str('@target G(\d+).S(\d+)'))


def load(filename):
    X = []
    g = None
    chunk_arr = []
    chunkd = defaultdict(dict)

    with open(filename) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            # comments match
            if COMMENT_REGEX.match(line):
                target_match = TARGET_REGEX.match(line)
                # look for target info
                if target_match:
                    # start keeping track of g for the new group
                    g, s = [int(x) for x in target_match.groups()]
                    # reset x
                    X = []
            # chunk termination string match
            elif TERMINATION_REGEX.match(line):
                if g is not None:
                    # create a np.array out of the previous chunk's data
                    X = np.array(X)
                    chunkd[g][s] = X
            # data found
            else:
                # append data as a 2-element tuple onto a 1D list
                X.append(tuple([float(x) for x in line.split()]))

    return chunkd
```

Access is made simply by passing the proper G,S coordinate to the returned `chunk_arr`.

```
arr = load('chunks.txt')
print(arr[1][1])
[[ -1.08847000e+01   4.89034000e-05]
[ -1.08711000e+01   4.91023000e-05]
[ -1.08574000e+01   4.93062000e-05]
[ -1.08438000e+01   4.95075000e-05]
[ -1.08302000e+01   4.97094000e-05]]
```