# Read several data sets from same file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file (input for a FE calculation) from which I want to read and store several sets with different kind of information:

```
...  
*Nodeset,name=set1  
0,1,2,3,5...  
*Nodeset,name=set2  
1000,1201,1352,...  
...
```

or

```
*SECTION, TYPE=BOX, ELEMENTSET=set1   
0.10,0.05,0.005,0.005,0.005,0.005  
-0.1118, 0.0, -0.9936  
200.E9,80.E9
```

My question is how to read and store each set separately with the following preconditions:

- There are several sets of varying length and number within a file
- The sets are of minor size compared to the total file size
- Both name and content is needed for further calculations

Is it possible to read the file only once and directly store the data? Or do I have to create a dictionary with the name and line of the set and then read the data for each set individually?

Comment: `numpy.genfromtxt` accepts generators in place of files. You can therefore use iterator techniques to filter your file and get all the processing done in one go while leaving the number parts to numpy. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42510994/7207392) an admittedly comparatively primitive example that demonstrated the principle.

Comment: Do you need a `numpy.array` comprising all your sets? numpy arrays work best with homogeneous data, which you do not have here, so it may be best to store your data in a `dict`-like structure, where each key is a set name and its value is a `numpy.array` of content.

Comment: I think at some point , I am goint to create a class object which stores the set name, its properties, nodes, etc. , Hence the question is ,how to best prepare the data from the file for this ?

Comment: If that's the case, I'd use a `dict` as I've described. Take a stab at it and reply back if you need assistance

Comment: There are two issues - how do you parse each line or group of lines? and how do you collect the resulting data for later use?  It's easy to read a line, split it on ',', and get names and lists of numbers.  The main tools for collecting items are lists, dictionaries and your own object classes.  Do you know anything about the source of this file?  Did it use a library in Python or other language?

Comment: Basically it is a ABAQUS *.inp file which I think is based on Python somehow.